# Location Update from Work Manager Doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, android-fusedlocation

Recently I've been trying to implement the logic in order to get Location Updates from a FusedLocationProviderClient using Work Manager, every 15 mins (as that's the minimum background execution delay). However requestLocationUpdates() function from FusedLocationProviderClient is failing every 15 minutes, and I cannot get success result task from it, I'm always getting failed result. And when I print the exception from fusedlocationproviderclient it just prints "null"? Any help?

Fragment:

```
private fun addWorker(){
        val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext())
        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "MyMainWorker",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
            workRequest
        )
}
```

Worker

```
class MyWorker(context: Context, wp: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, wp) {

    private val LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(4)
    private val LOCATION_FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2)

    private var ctx: Context = context

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return if (getLocationUpdate()) {
            Log.d("MyWorker", "SUCCESS")
            Result.success()
        } else {
            Log.d("MyWorker", "FAILURE")
            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLocationUpdate(): Boolean {

       val fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(ctx)

        val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(result: LocationResult?) {
                super.onLocationResult(result)
                result?.locations?.let { locations ->
                    for (location in locations) {
                        Log.d("MyWorker", "NEW Location: $location")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        val locationRequest = LocationRequest().apply {
            interval = LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL
            fastestInterval = LOCATION_FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
        val result = fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
        Log.d("MyWorker", result.exception?.message.toString())
        Log.d("MyWorker", result.exception?.cause.toString())
        Log.d("MyWorker", result.exception.toString())
        return result.isSuccessful
    }
```

Error

> I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result FAILURE for Work [
> id=3fe5b78d-e0ed-4348-90b6-25c2c1f96bfd, tags={
> com.example.testapp.MyWorker } ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: The Google Play store has updated its policy concerning device
> location, restricting background location access to apps that need it
> for their core functionality and meet related policy requirements.
> Adopting these best practices doesn't guarantee Google Play approves
> your app's usage of location in the background.
>
> Learn more about the policy changes related to device location.
> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150